# TransformationFunctions accepting numerical values

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wish to change the form of expressions like

```
r^{-1-n} a^n
```

combining the powers in Mathematica to give

```
[(a/r)^n] / r.
```

To achieve this I have written this TransformationFunction

```
PowerReduce[Times[Power[a_, -1 - b_], Power[c_, b_]]] := Power[a, -1] Power[c/a, b]
```

which works on examples like this

```
Simplify[Power[r, -1 - n] Power[a, n], TransformationFunctions -> PowerReduce]
```

but fails if I use numerical values, say `r=2`:

```
Simplify[ Power[2, -1 - n] Power[a, n], TransformationFunctions -> PowerReduce]
```

Other TransformFunctions seem to work with numerical values. For example, the following works well with both numerical and algebraic values.

```
MultAllVals[Power[a_, b_]] := a b
Simplify[ Power[2, -1 - n] Power[a, n], TransformationFunctions -> MultAllVals]
```

How can I get Mathematica to group the powers of `n` together in to a single Power[ ] ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is really in automatic simplifications, and those are hard to fight. In a number of cases, Mathematica will transform an input into an equivalent form that it considers simpler, automatically, without asking the user, and without requiring the use of any of `Simplify` - family functions. Whether or not such simplifications were a right design choice is a matter of opinion. In some cases they are quite useful, but it is hard to undo such simplifications.

In your particular case, consider:

```
In[55]:= (a/2)^n/2
Out[55]= 2^(-1-n) a^n
```

So, your specific case is doomed, no matter whether or not your transformation really works. It does, in fact, which you can easily check by including some `Print` statement into the r.h.s. of `PowerReduce`. One way out is to define your own functions like `times`, `power`, etc, and let them decay into `Times`, `Power`, etc at some point / in some cases. With this approach however, you immediately lose the main advantage of `Simplify` etc with built-ins like `Times` and `Power` - namely the huge and tested built-in rule base inter-relating these functions. One can perhaps devise some hybrid approach which would use both on different parts of expression to be simplified, but this seems bound to be problem - specific.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer.

Comment: My personal auto-simplify pet peeve is `1 + i` becoming `Complex[1,1]` internally. This is especially frustrating if this is pare of a larger equation where you wish to separate the real and imaginary parts. But, it can be dealt with by applying `#/. Complex[a_,b_]:> a + q b`, simplifying, and reversing the transformation.

Comment: @Leonid, btw ~9 more upvotes to the first gold Mathematica badge!

Comment: @rcollyer Indeed! But belisarius may make it sooner, which will only be right.

Comment: @Leonid, more right, possibly. Likely, (55 upvotes vs. 9 answers) not really.